# Is access token required even when publish_stream is granted?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am a newbie to facebook opengraph and creating facebook applications. I have developed an app in facebook and going by the opengraph tutorial I have inserted the necessary meta tags. Testing the app privately, "publish_stream" permission have been granted. Is it necessary to obtain user access token even if publish_stream permission has been granted by the user? How can one obtain user token?

```
function Visit_Link()
{   
    $config = array();
    $config['appId'] = 'APP ID';
    $config['secret'] = 'APP SECRET';

    $facebook = new Facebook($config);
    $response = $facebook->api(
    'me/namespace:action',
    'POST',
    array(
            'website' => "WEBSITE",

        )
        );

    print_r($response);
}
```

The error displayed is `Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in`
P.S I am using fb php sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you do need the access token, a long lived one preferably (which last for 60 days). If you are testing your app with the graph api explorer token, you will always need a new one after 30 min or so, because it short-lived. Use [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/) to login your user, because it will always return a long lived access token which you can store in the DB for offline-access (which facebook deprecated and introduced the long lived access tokens).